# Meaning of filelocation = "../"//filename

Tags: fortran, fortran90

```
    filelocation = "../"//filename
    PRINT *, "Attempting to open ", TRIM(filename)
    OPEN(fh1, FILE = filelocation, STATUS='old',IOSTAT = io)
```

Can anyone tell me please what is the meaning of "../"// in the first line?

Answer (score 1):

The string

```
../
```

is Linux for *the parent directory of the current working directory*.  This may or may not work on a Windows machine.  The two characters

```
//
```

represent the Fortran operator for string concatenation.  So

```
"../"//filename
```

sets `filelocation` to refer to a file named `filename` in the parent directory of the directory the program thinks it is executing in.